# customize jsf validator msg

Tags: jsf, validation

I have the following in my messages.properties file:

javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Please enter a value for {0}
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM = At least {0} characters are required for {1}
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM = At most {0} characters are required for {1}

when the error occurs, I got these outputs:

At most 8 characters are required for pwd At most 8 characters are required for pwd 
At least 6 characters are required for pwd  At least 6 characters are required for pwd

As it shows, it repeats, how can I change the msg to just appear once?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the `for=""` of `<h:message/>` tag and anyway try playing with `redisplay="false"` for `<h:message` tag and `globalOnly="true"` of `<h:messages` tag

Comment: `redisplay` is a Primefaces feature.

Comment: @MattHandy seems that you are right , I wonder why my eclipse auto complete offered it to me (for h:messages) , even with some documentation....

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using <t:messages tag. after I set globalOnly to true, it doesn't show error msg at all...

Comment: try placing several <t:message/> with for , where the for points to id of the input